# Docker container instantly exits upon creation

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to follow this tutorial [docker tutorial](https://datasciencedojo.com/blog/web_app_for_gradio/#), but when I get to the part about creating/running the container in Step 7.2, the container instantly exits. The image build seems to work just fine though. Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.6
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 

COPY requirements.txt ./ 

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt 

COPY . . 

CMD ["python3", "./app.py"]
```

Here is the requirements file

```
gradio
torch
timm
sentencepiece
transformers
python==3.11.6
```

And here are the image build and container run commands I've used.

```
docker build -t demo-gradio-app .
```

```
docker run -it -d --name my-app -p 7000:7000 demo-gradio-app
```

Running docker logs "CONTAINER ID" returns nothing. Any idea after I run the container, why the status is Exited and doesn't persist? Also, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your program exits for some reason and when it does that, the container stops. You should be able to see the logs using `docker logs my-app` since you've name the container 'my-app' in your `docker run` command.

Comment: As a starter you should remove the `-d` to stay attached to the container.

Comment: in order to debug this issue we need the source code, I tried with a simple `app.py` for gradio and it works fine.

Comment: I figured it out y'all. I had a typo in the Dockerfile, where I was pointing to the wrong .py file. It's been a long week.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied the sample `app.py` provided in the DataScienceDojo example that you have mentioned.  It appears that there is a bad character in the code provided (when I run it without the `-d` flag):

```
$ docker run -it --name my-app -p 7000:7000 demo-gradio-app
  File "/usr/src/app/./app.py", line 13
      prediction = classifier(emotion_input,) 
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+202F
```

After fixing the spacing issue, it works:

```
$ docker run -it --name my-app -p 7000:7000 demo-gradio-app
Downloading (…)lve/main/config.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 768/768 [00:00<00:00, 476kB/s]
Downloading pytorch_model.bin: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 268M/268M [00:18<00:00, 14.6MB/s]
Downloading (…)okenizer_config.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 291/291 [00:00<00:00, 361kB/s]
Downloading (…)solve/main/vocab.txt: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 232k/232k [00:00<00:00, 847kB/s]
Downloading (…)cial_tokens_map.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 112/112 [00:00<00:00, 257kB/s]
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py:105: UserWarning: `return_all_scores` is now deprecated,  if want a similar functionality use `top_k=None` instead of `return_all_scores=True` or `top_k=1` instead of `return_all_scores=False`.
  warnings.warn(
Running on local URL:  http://0.0.0.0:7000
```

Now with the `-d` flag:

```
$ docker run -itd --name my-app -p 7000:7000 demo-gradio-app
767fea1084a84c5b38d386cfde93e208438553a8bba57acced4ed833a8541073

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND              CREATED         STATUS        PORTS                                       NAMES
767fea1084a8   demo-gradio-app   "python3 ./app.py"   3 seconds ago   Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:7000->7000/tcp, :::7000->7000/tcp   my-app
```